# the usage of 'with us' in 'Thank you for shopping with us'

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I can see 'with us' on bus or on supermarket walls like

> Thank you for traveling with us (on bus)

or

> Thank you for shopping with us (in a supermarket).

I am confused why don't use 'travel by us' or 'shop at us' etc. does 'with' here has some extra meaning compared to those words?

Comment: It's just a very common ***marketing*** device - intended to imply a closer relationship between user and supplier (of products, services, etc.) than actually exists.

Comment: The choice of preposition in any given language is usually kind of arbitrary.  We say "with", but other languages might use their version of "for", or "around", or "by", or anything.  Don't look for too much meaning in specific prepositions, and just learn that that's the one we normally use.

Answer (score 4):

It's grammatically correct, if by "us" you mean all the people who work for the bus company or the supermarket.

Using the word "with" is an attempt to create an emotional bond between the customer and the otherwise faceless business.